# Pages File edited on iPhone and synced with iCloud on OS X EL Capitan, Getting dotted cloud icon

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, macos, pages

I have a file that I uploaded from pages app on my iPhone IOS 9.2.1 and synced with iCloud , but on my mac I see this file with dotted cloud icon and not the latest changes to this file.

[image]

How can I make it sync ?

Answer (score 1):

[This link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203564) can be helpful for you to understand what's going on. Please refer also to the following pics, to see what's exactly your case.

In general, a dotted-lined iCloud icon means that it is waiting to be uploaded.

[image]

[image]

In order to force the sync, you can try to open the document that you are trying to upload, make whatever modification to the file (even just a point or a comma somewhere) and then save. In this way, you should make the file sync.

Comment: I have waited it to upload more then one hour, can I force it to upload ?

Comment: Try to: 
1) delete the file from iCloud, and then re-upload again
or 
2) opening the documents that you are trying to upload, making whatever modification to the file (even just a point or a comma somewhere) and then save. In this way, you should make the file sync.

Comment: I have tried it and no luck, still I get this dotted cloud icon near my document